# How can I regain use of portable drive?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, kubuntu

I use Kubuntu 16.04 with an Intel i7 64 bit processor, and Windows 10 when I must, on a desktop. I have a WD MyPassport 2TB drive which I occasionally use for backup which is usually not connected to the desktop.

I have successfully written to this drive several times with both Kubuntu and Windows, my latest back up from the latter. I now have an error message [image] but have since rebooted to Windows and been able to read and write to the drive. What has gone wrong in Kubuntu, and can I regain the ability to both read and write to the drive in Kubuntu as I can in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the NTFS drives are mounting as read-only, or not mounting at all, it's probably because Kubuntu thinks their filesystems are unclean, probably due to hibernation, or a damaged file system. Do this...

## in Windows

- boot into Windows
- open the Power control panel
- choose `change what the power buttons do`
- choose `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast startup`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off`
- type `chkdsk /f c:`
- approve to run chkdsk at next reboot
- type `chkdsk /f x:` (replacing "x" with drive letters of other **visible** NTFS partitions or drives)
- reboot into Windows to let chkdsk run on drive C:

Comment: Thank you; I believe chkdsk will take a long time, some of the NTFS partitions, including C: reside on a SSD, and I once somehow lost data running chldsk. The present situation is that, apart from Linux not mounting the portable drive, I can read and write to C: and all other NTFS partitions in both Windows and Linux except that a very small minority of unimportant files are inaccessible to either Windows or Linux. Therefore, in view of the risks and time involved, is it really necessary to run chkdsk on the entirely healthy partitions?

Comment: @WGCman lost data because of chkdsk is very very unusual, and would only occur if the drive/partition was really really messed up... and who knows the condition of files are anyway. If the drive/partition in question mounts only in r/o mode, and you're ok with that, then skip the chkdsk. If you need the drive/partition to be r/w, backup the data, then run chkdsk, and at least you'll have a recovery if data does get lost. But overall, I'd say the risk is very very low. You can still do the other commands in my answer either way.

Comment: Thanks again @heynnema. I am going away and will run chkdsk on my portable drive when I return; shall certainly vote/accept then! I now realise my first post was ambiguous. My 2TB portable drive is not partitioned; the several partitions on the desktop are backed up as folders on the 2TB. The desktop partitions all appear healthy, only the 2TB has a problem it is inaccessible by Linux but r/w in Windws.

Comment: Now starting to do this, I performed step 4 (Change unavailable options) but don't see any ref to fast startup. Is this because my Windows 10 is already set to Never sleep, and therefore step 8 will merely confirm the status quo? (I have read that fast startup is automatically disabled when Hibernation is off.)

Comment: Yes, fast startup option is hidden/disabled when hibernation is off. To confirm, do `powercfg /h on` and follow all of the steps again (you'll turn it off again later).

Comment: Thanks, heynnema, this worked. I established that hibernation was turned off on my desktop - probably a sensible move by the people who built it, knowing I planned to use two operating systems. CHKDSK found many files whose names it didn't like (perhaps too long for Windows), but I found no evidence that anything was missing.